# How to check if a vector contains a given value and add a number to it so it becomes unique?

Tags: r, database, vector

So I have a database with id data "time" that may repeat itself and if it does I have to add a nanosecond to it so it becomes unique.

[link to the data sample] "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NcAS5alpVs3nAJYi9X_8JB7Z09Ao3I1Q/view?usp=sharing"

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
Dati <- list(Dati[,1:3], Dati[,5:7], Dati[,9:11])
Dati <- ldply(Dati, function(x){
  names(x)[1] <- "time" 
  return(x)})


library(reshape2)
dm <- melt(Dati)
dm <- dm %>% na.exclude %>% dcast(time ~ variable, mean)
head(dm, 3)
```

This code melts the unique time values together; however, my goal is to add a small value to the time values that are repeated so the melt function does not melt it together. Does anyone know how to do this? I have ran out of ideas.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data (you can use `dput` to do that) along with expected outcome

Comment: Pardon? I did not quite understand, what should I do?

Comment: I will add the expected result as a picture shortly.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somnething like this?

```
df %>% 
     mutate(tm = lubridate::dmy_hms(Time_bid)) %>% 
     group_by(tm) %>% 
     mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     mutate( tm1 = ifelse(ind>1 , lubridate::dmy_hms(Time_bid) + lubridate::nanoseconds(ind),lubridate::dmy_hms(Time_bid))) %>% 
     group_by(tm1) %>% 
     summarise_at(vars(Price_ask),mean) %>% 
     mutate(tm1 = as_datetime(tm1))

# A tibble: 20,666 x 2
   tm1                 Price_ask
   <dttm>                  <dbl>
 1 2019-07-01 09:00:00      26.4
 2 2019-07-01 09:00:01      26.4
 3 2019-07-01 09:00:04      26.4
 4 2019-07-01 09:00:05      26.4
 5 2019-07-01 09:00:07      26.4
 6 2019-07-01 09:00:09      26.2
 7 2019-07-01 09:00:11      26.2
 8 2019-07-01 09:00:14      26.2
 9 2019-07-01 09:00:18      26.2
10 2019-07-01 09:00:30      26.2
# ... with 20,656 more rows
```